# The integral of $\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} \frac{t^4\tan(t)}{2+\cos(t)}\,dt$?

Tags: calculus, integration

Here is the definite integral: $$\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} \frac{t^4\tan(t)}{2+\cos(t)}\,dt$$

Apparently this evaluates to zero. I don't see any patterns at all and I have no idea how I'd evaluate it. I tried graphing this on desmos and it wasn't pretty; there are asymptotes everywhere. Shouldn't this be undefined because of the asymptotes? Even if it isn't undefined, what would the antiderivative of this possible be?

And most importantly, why does it evaluate to zero, and is there something that should've told me that?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You will find that definite integral questions with funky integrands are not generally solvable by the routine method of taking the anti-derivative, as it may be very hard to find.

Note that here, the integrand is an odd function.

$f(t)=\frac{t^4\tan t}{2+\cos t}\implies f(-t)=-\frac{t^4\tan t}{2+\cos t}=-f(t)$

Recall that for an odd function $f, \int_{-a}^af=0$

As far as asymptotes and discontinuity of $f$ is concerned, note that $f$ is only discontinuous at odd multiples of $\pi/2$ and the domain of $t, (-\pi/4, +\pi/4)$ does not contain any points of discontinuity.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was a very simply but thorough addressed all my questions, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$\frac{(-t)^4\tan(-t)}{2+\cos(-t)}=-\frac{t^4\tan(t)}{2+\cos(t)}$$

Comment: Yes I noticed that and now the answer seems very obvious haha, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int_{-a}^{a}\frac{t^4\tan t}{2+\cos t}\mathrm dt$$
$t=-u$:
$$I=\int_{a}^{-a}\frac{(-u)^4\tan(-u)}{2+\cos(-u)}(-\mathrm du)$$
$$I=\int_{a}^{-a}\frac{u^4(-\tan u)}{2+\cos u}(-\mathrm du)$$
$$I=\int_{a}^{-a}\frac{u^4\tan u}{2+\cos u}\mathrm du$$
$$I=-\int_{-a}^{a}\frac{u^4\tan u}{2+\cos u}\mathrm du$$
$$I=-I$$
$$2I=0$$
$$I=0$$
QED

Comment: It's nice to see a straight up proof, didn't know you could do this using the property of even/odd, thank you!

Comment: @JamesRonald You're very welcome. It's always a good thing to try when you are unsure of how to start on an integral.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_{-a}^af(t)\mathrm dt=0$$
if $f$ is an odd function. That's because odd functions are symmetric w.r.t. the origin, then if $f$ from $0$ to $a$ is defined in the first quadrant (positive area), from $-a$ to $0$ $f$ is defined in the third quadrant (negative area), thus the two areas cancel out.

Comment: That definitely makes sense, thank you!

Comment: You are welcome!